# How to get the whole word by right click on the Text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm developing a Python Tkinter-based GUI app. I would like to get the whole word that is under the mouse cursor on the right-click on the Text widget. I've tried:

```
from tkinter import *


def get_the_word(event):
    """Prints the index of the char, that was under the mouse cursor"""
    print(textbox.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y)))

root = Tk()  # create the root window
textbox = Text(root)  # create a Text widget
textbox.grid()  # show the widget using grid geometry manager
textbox.bind("<Button-3>", get_the_word)  # bind the get_the_word(event) function to the right-click
root.mainloop()  # start the mainloop
```

But I need to get the whole word (or, at least, the start and the end indexes of the word), not the index of the only one character of the word.